# How to remove the space and display the data of text file in drop down list?

Tags: php

I have the following code which write into text file on getting the `project-code` as in variable `$data`, projectcode are read from `$my_file = 'masterprojectcode.txt';`

then below if condition executes

```
elseif(isset($_POST['masterprojectcodecheck'])){

    //remove project code from the master projectcode list

    $my_file = 'masterprojectcode.txt';

    $projectcodestring = file_get_contents($my_file);

    //print_r($projectcodestring);
    //print_r (explode("",$projectcodestring));
    //$projectcodestring = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/',' ', $projectcodestring);
    //print_r($projectcodestring);
    // echo(count($projectcodestring));

    $data = $_POST['addprojectcode'];

    $data = trim($data);

    if( strpos($projectcodestring, $data) !== false) {

        unlink($my_file);

        echo $data." found in a Master Project List and is removed successfully";

        $projectcodestring = str_replace($data, "", $projectcodestring);

        //print_r($projectcodestring);
       // print_r (explode("",$projectcodestring));
         //$projectcodestring = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/',' ', $projectcodestring);
         //print_r($projectcodestring);
        // echo(count($projectcodestring));

        file_put_contents($my_file, $projectcodestring);

    }else{

        echo $data." Projectcode Not found in a Master Project List";
    }


}
```

But it adds unnecessary white space when i try to delete inbetween projectcode and when i sort then all white space accumulate at top which is shown in second picture highlighted in dropdown, I tried by regular expression but it remove the `\n` also. please help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you highlight where the unwanted whitespace is added, exactly?

Comment: yes in the second picture above `COP-BRN-02`

Comment: `COP-INT` is not included in `<option>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small misstake here:

```
$projectcodestring = str_replace($data."\n", "", $projectcodestring);
```

This should do it.

Comment: how to check and remove duplicate in text such as `COP-BRN-06` occured 2 times in text file and is also show 2 times in drop list

Comment: please say something

Comment: I would take the file and split it by \n (explode) and then eliminate duplicates in the array

Comment: array_unique() is the function. After that write the array back to the file (or variable)